# Probability of getting a multiple of 5 by rolling a die with infinitely many faces

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, dice

The problem seems to contradict itself and that's why it puzzles me. Here's the full text:

Let there be an infinitely sided die where each face has an equal probability of appearing upon casting the die. Each side is marked $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$. What is the probability that upon casting this die a multiple of 5 appears?

How can this die form a uniformly distributed set?

Let p be the probability of rolling each number. Then $\sum p = 1$, but there are infinitely many $p$'s, so $p=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}$, which leads to $p = 0$, which, in\ turn, contradicts $\sum p=1$.

I know I am missing something, but what is it?

Comment: What is $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac {1}{n}$?

Comment: For large sets we can say the probability for number to be multiple of 5 is $1/5$

Comment: @KingTut Large, but not infinite.

Comment: For *infinite* sets we can say that. Not large.

Comment: Even for small if they contain $5k$ elements.

Comment: @user355705 It diverges, but that $\frac{1}{n}$ comes from another limit, so I don't quite understand why the harmonic series is important here. Care to explain?

Comment: It does not diverge. Check it for any $n$.

Comment: @KingTut How would that proof go for $\frac{1}{5}?$ I can make a bijection $f(n)=5n$ from  $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{5,10,\dots\}$ which would give a probability of $1$. $\frac{1}{5}$ is the intuitive answer here, but intuition doesn't help much with probabilities.

Comment: For the question of whether the outcomes can be uniformly distributed, see ["Prove there exists no uniform distribution on a countable and infinite set"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/255667/396325).

Comment: @Escu what user355705 said is that sum of probabilities is $1$. you need to take care with infinite sums. The limit of sum is not necessarily sum of limits. Here $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} n^{-1} = 1 \neq  \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\lim_{n\to \infty} n^{-1}) = 0$

Comment: @Escu Simple argument can be that probability of multiples of $5$ if we have $5k+q, q\in[0,4]$ will be $\frac{k}{5k+q}$ now take the limit as $k \to \infty$

Comment: You don't seem to be missing anything - there's  no suuch thing as an infinite-sided die where each face has equal probability.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich One can consider infinite-sided die in the same way as one considers infinity in general. And the limit given for the probability in question in a comment above certainly exists and equals to 1/5.

Comment: @user355705 I didn't say one couldn't consider an infinite-sided die. And I didn't say anything about limits of probabilities. A limit of probabilitites is not the same thing as a probability. There is no such thing as an infinite-sided die where each face has the same probability of appearing.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich  You are right. In fact I never saw a die with more than 20 faces.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible for a random variable $X$ that takes a countably infinite number of values $\{1,2,...\}$ to be uniformly distributed. To see this, imagine $$ \exists \ p \in [0,1] \ \ \forall i \in \{1,2,...\}: P(X = i) = p.$$ Then we immediately get the contradiction: $$ 1 = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P(X=i) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} p \in \{0, \infty\}.  $$
So your problem is indeed ill-posed since the die your describe cannot possibly exist.