# What is the probability of finding 2 in set of primes?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let
$$S=\{p :p\in\mathbb{P}\}$$
Be the set of primes. So $2$ is also a member of it right?
$$P[\text{ finding 2 in $S$}]=\frac{1}{\infty}=0 ??$$
Does that mean that probability of finding $2$ from the set of primes is $0$. But that's senseless as $2$ is a prime??

Comment: This [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely) might help you. You may need to study about Lebesgue measure.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with primes—it's just a question about randomly selecting one element of an infinite set. And without specifying the random distribution you're using on your infinite set, it's impossible to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It is impossible to define a uniform distribution on a countably infinite set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255667/prove-there-exists-no-uniform-distribution-on-a-countable-and-infinite-set),  so I assume you are talking about computing the desired probability as the size of the set approaches infinity.

Let $S_k$ denote the set of the first $k$ prime numbers, so $S_{1} = \{2\}$, $S_{2} = \{2, 3\}$, etc. Define $S = \lim_{k\to\infty} S_{k}$.

For fixed $k$, the likelihood of picking the integer $2$ in $S_{k}$ is equal to $1/k$. As $k\to\infty$, this goes to zero, so the result follows for $S$.

Comment: Why is the likelihood of picking $2$ in $S_k$ not $1/k$?

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, in general $1/k$ doesn't equal to $k$ either...

Comment: @Ekesh Kumar, the link in your answer seems convincing to me. But i was just wondering how mathematicians study probability on countably infinite sets?

Comment: @Rahul, you can't study probability on **any** set without specifying a probability distribution. For finite sets (and for some uncountably infinite sets like the reals) the uniform distribution is available (but not always the one you want to use). For countably infinite sets, there is no uniform distribution, but there are plenty of others. You just have to use the one that's appropriate for whatever problem you're working on.

Comment: Understood, Rahul?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define *how you "find" a prime*.

If, for example, you enumerate primes one by one ($2,3,5,\ldots$) and you toss a coin for every prime you name, and you stop and "find" the prime the first time you get "tails", then the probability of "finding" $2$ is $50\%$, the probability of "finding" $3$ is $25\%$ etc.

Worth adding that there is no way to pick a prime out of the (infinite) set of all primes so that each is equally probable: either the probability is $0$ so $0=\sum_\mathbb{P} 0 =1$ (contradiction) or it is some nonzero number $q>0$ so $\infty=\sum_\mathbb{P} q=1$ (contradiction again).